# Google Sheets Script Error - Cannot read property '1' of null (line 7)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using the following script to pull data from bulk json files:

```
function importRegex(url, regexInput) {
  var output = '';
  var fetchedUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  if (fetchedUrl) {
    var html = fetchedUrl.getContentText();
    if (html.length && regexInput.length) {
      output = html.match(new RegExp(regexInput, 'i'))[1];
    }
  }
  // Grace period to not overload
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  return output;
}
```

Then this formula with the desired URL in E3:

```
=IMPORTREGEX(E3,"(.*')")
```

It worked completely fine to begin with, now I'm suddenly getting the error, seemingly without making any changes, any tips?

Comment: `'` is not present in the response.

Comment: @idfurw you are right, thank you. Not sure how I accidentally added that without noticing!

Comment: Did the previous comment solve the issue? If so, please add-it as a solution or the user who mentioned to do it.

Comment: @Kessy How do I mark a comment as a solution?

Comment: You can post the answer yourself explaining the change to the code you did

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of lacking a null check.
You are now using the return value of `html.match()` whether it is null or not.
So you should check if the return value is null and if it has enough length.
Like this:

```js
if (html.length && regexInput.length) {
  let match = html.match(new RegExp(regexInput, 'i'));
  if ( match != null && match.length > 1 ){
    output = match[1];
  }
}
```